# How to get rid of js inside jquery loaded element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, web, jquery-plugins

I'm creating a single page application with JQuery load() method.

The situation is, every PHP file I load with jquery has a JS inside it,

The problem is the JS inside every PHP app keeps using even though it was overridden when i load another file inside the same element.
 and it gives me some conflict with every file i loaded since the js are used interchangeably.

take it as an example:

file1.php

```
 <input id="supplier" name="supplier" onblur="highlight()">
 <script>
    function highlight(){}
 </script>
```

file2.php

```
 <input id="supplier" name="supplier" onblur="highlight()">
 <script>
    function highlight(){}
 </script>
```

PROBLEM: file1.php js still executed on file2.php same with file2.php to file1.php even though  file1 is overridden with file2 with jquery load

is there a way to clean a jquery inside the element which I had overridden?

Comment: Hi Eeshiro. Thanks for posting on SO. Is there any chance you could clean up your question a bit? It's extremely difficult to understand what your problem is and what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

According to the jQuery.load documentation, passing a selector to the load method will remove all the scripts.

http://api.jquery.com/load/#script-execution

`$('.my-element').load('my-php-file.php #supplier');`